# easiest way to check if an item is in `has_many` field of another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have 3 tables, `cooler`,`cpu`,`socket`. A `cooler` (supports/)`has_many` `sockets` and `cpu` `belongs_to` `socket`. Now I what is the easiest way to check if `cooler` supports `cpu` or not?

```
@cooler.sockets.include? @cpu.socket # => False always no matter what
```

I tried to check types using:

```
@cooler.sockets.class
#=> #Socket::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
@cooler.sockets.include? @cpu.socket
```

always returns `false`, because here you are trying to check if `Cpu`'s model instance `socket` attribute is contained in the array of `Socket` model instances corresponding to the `Cooler` model instance, and that can never possibly happen.

However, you can accomplish what you want with `.exists?`:

```
@cooler.sockets.exists?(socket: @cpu.socket)
```

or `.present?`:

```
@cooler.sockets.where(socket: @cpu.socket).present?
```

Answer (score 3):

[@suslov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30826510/2767755) explained and gave couple of ways to solve your requirement. Here is one way, I can think of :

```
@cooler.sockets.where(socket: @cpu.socket).any?
```

Read the [`any?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-any-3F) method.